# SSIS Execute Process Task: Is there a way to get the exit code?

Tags: ssis

It is simple to set which exit code means success.  But I am hoping to get the process exit code and use it to differentiate between different types of errors.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ExecValueVariable property of the Execute Process task. It's [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.taskhost.execvaluevariable.aspx) in the programming reference for SSIS, but you can set it directly in the Properties window for the task. It captures [different values for different task types](http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Have-you-used-the-ExecutionValue-and-ExecValueVariable-properties.aspx); for the Execute Process task it captures the return code from the process.